# DocumentMissingException in ElasticSearch doing bulk update by Ids but routing by field

Tags: routes, elasticsearch, bulk

Running ES 1.3.4:

- With routing defaulted to by document index - indexing, searches, and bulk updates work!
- With Routing defined in my index mapping to route by a document field, i.e., “_routing” with
  path = a document field name - then routing is working with indexing, search, and updates where I have the entire doc to set routing by, but Bulk script Updates by Id fail.

Code is:

```
updateBulkDocumentsWithScript(List<String> ids, String updateScript) {

    final BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequestBuilder = esClient.prepareBulk();
    for (String id : ids) {
        UpdateRequestBuilder updateRequestBuilder = esClient.prepareUpdate()
                .setIndex(index)
                .setType(type)
                .setId(id)
                // We are routing by a field but just have the Id!
                    // .setRouting(routing)
                .setScript(updateScript, ScriptType.INLINE);

        bulkRequestBuilder.add(updateRequestBuilder);
    }

    final BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
}
```

So you see I am not explicitly setting routing here - I assumed calling setId(id) for the request would route the request properly, even when routing is set to a document field other than the default = Id.

If mapping routing is defined "required" : "true" - I get an NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkResponse.writeTo(BulkResponse.java:116)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransportChannel.sendResponse
(NettyTransportChannel.java:91)
```

and it appears all the Bulk request responses are null - maybe because routing is required.

If mapping routing is defined "required" : "false" - I get a bunch of DocumentMissingException in bulkResponse.buildFailureMessage():

```
DocumentMissingException[[index][-1] [type][h4s_jzsKQDaAqcascSEOyg]: document missing]
```

Is what I am trying to do impossible - BulkUpdate by Id when I have the Id, but when routing is not by Id? Or is this an ES bug. I would think given an Id that ES would be able to find the document even if a different routing is set.